# What should be the sample size in a stratified random sample to get the same precision of a simple random sample?

Tags: variance, sampling, sample-size, central-limit-theorem

I was reading example 3.2 on stratified sampling in *Sampling: Design and Analysis* by Lohr where a stratified random sampling design is proposed and compared with a simple random sample one.

The point was estimating the total of the variable of interest. The simple random sample was about the 10% of the population ($n=300$) and in the stratified random sampling **each stratum was sampled with the same frequency**.

After the calculation of the estimated variance for each stratum and the estimated variance of the simple random sample, at about the end of the example the author claims :

> the relative gain from stratification can be estimated by the ratio
> $$ \frac{\text{estimated variance from stratified sample, with } n =300}{\text{estimated variance from simple random sample, with } n=300 }  = 0.75$$
> If these figures were the population variances, we would expect that we would need only $300 \cdot 0.75 = 225$ observations with a stratified sample to obtain the same precision from an SRS of $300$ observations.

Initially I didn't understand why this simple calculation gave the correct result, but then I came up with a (hopefully sound) mathematical explanation:

Given that the estimated totals in the population for a variable $Y$ in each case are defined, maybe abusing a bit the notation, as
$$\hat{t}_{SRS} = N\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$$
$$\hat{t}_{STR} = \sum_{h=1}^H \hat{t}_h =  \sum_{h=1}^H (N_h \sum_{i=1}^{n_h} y_{ih})$$

we have that the variance of the estimators of the totals, if we sample a proportion $\alpha$ in each stratum and in the simple random sample, are

$$V(\hat{t}_{SRS}) = (1-\frac{n}{N}) N^2 \frac{S^2}{n} = \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha} N S^2$$
$$V(\hat{t}_{STR}) = \sum _{h=1}^H (1-\frac{n_h}{N_h}) N_h^2 \frac{S_h^2}{n_h} = \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha} \sum _{h=1}^H N_h S_h^2$$

So the ratio calculated by the author is equal to

$$k = \frac{\sum _{h=1}^H N_h S_h^2}{N S^2} $$

under the hypothesis that the sample variances are instead population variances.

So given that the assumption for the use of the central limit theorem are satisfied we can say that to have the same precision (i.e. the same confidence interval) from a stratified sample and from a simple random sample with proportion $\alpha$,  we should find $\beta$ such that

$$ \frac{1-\beta}{\beta} \sum _{h=1}^H N_h S_h^2 = \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha} N S^2 \iff \beta = \frac{\alpha k}{1+\alpha(k -1)}$$

which means also that

$$ n_{STR} = \beta N = \frac{k}{1+\alpha (k -1)} n_{SRS}$$

So when $\alpha \to 0$ or $ k \to 1 $ we can say that $n_{STR} \approx k \cdot n_{SRS}$.

So what the author did was calculating this approximation, indeed if I use the exact formula the result becomes $n_{STR} = \frac{300 \cdot 0.75}{1+0.1(0.75-1)} \approx 231$ instead of $n_{STR}=225$.

So, since there was no further explaination in the book about this, I'd like to ask: is this reasoning sound or is there something wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: +1. But I suspect the author had something more basic in mind.  Because the standard errors of many estimators vary inversely with the square root of the sample size, precision ratios (equivalently, variance ratios) equal sample size ratios.  It's that simple.

Comment: thanks you very much @whuber for the simple explaination of what the author had in mind which I didn't get, but anyway do you agree that this is just an approximation, right?

Comment: Yes, it is an approximation, although in many practical settings it is exact.  This is a basic element of statistical thinking, because it shows directly how decreasing the variance of an estimate is tantamount to collecting your data for a proportionately smaller cost.  That's one reason applied statisticians are so interested in variances!